# (13)Permission denied with apache on centos

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

When accessing domain.com I'm getting this error in `domain.com-error_log`:

`[Mon Aug 20 17:07:48 2012] [error] [client X.X.X.X] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied`

I have virtual host for `domain.com`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/kir/domain.com
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    ErrorLog logs/domain.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/domain.com-access_log common
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    <Directory /home/kir/domain.com>
        RewriteEngine on
        Order allow,deny
        AllowOverride all
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

DocumentRoot `/home/kir/domain.com/` have permissions: `Permissions: drwxr-xr-x (0755); User: kir/kir`

After restarting httpd I have the following in `error.log`:

```
[Mon Aug 20 17:04:39 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Aug 20 17:04:40 2012] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context root:system_r:httpd_t
[Mon Aug 20 17:04:40 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Aug 20 17:04:40 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Aug 20 17:04:40 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Aug 20 17:04:40 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

As I'm using CentOs, I've tried to disabled SELinux (`/etc/selinux/config.conf` `SELINUX=disabled` ; `reboot`). 
After disabling SELinux I've tried again - the same thing, the same error (13)Permission denied...

UPD: When accessing domain.com/test.html (this file exists in DocumentRoot) the same thing (13)Permission denied.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you still get the SELinux-message in your logfile after disabling SELinux?

Comment: @pkhamre, nope, there is no SELinux message in `error.log` after disabling SELinux and rebooting httpd.

Comment: What are the permissions for `/home/kir` ?

Comment: @pkhamre, `drwx------ (0700)`

Comment: Maybe this permits Apache to access directories beyond. Can you do a test by changing mode to `0755` and see if it works?

Comment: @pkhamre, great! I've set 0755 to DocumentRoot's parent directory and now I'm able to download `domain.com/test.html`, but still getting (13)Permissions denied for `/`

Comment: @pkhamre, everything is ok now! Thank you! Please make an answer to my question. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have an index file in the directory, or do you allow directory listing in Apache? What do you expect to see at `/` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent directory of your `DirectoryRoot` must be accessible by Apache, so you must make sure that Apache got execute rights for `/home/kir`.

```
chmod 0755 /home/kir
```

or

```
chown kir:apache /home/kir
chmod 0750 /home/kir
```